# Regex in Scala giving unexpected additional results

Tags: scala, databricks

I want to identify columns which start with the characters id

we tried ^id* and also ^(id)* which work in Regexr but not in Scala

Regexr:

[RegExr screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ncu9K.png)

Scala (Databricks)

[Databricks Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iEHt9.png)

Comment: "work in Regexr but not in Scala" - they both work, but your regex's don't do what you think they're doing. Part of the problem is your RegExr regex is `^(id)*` (closest to correct, but matches on `idid` too, might be sufficient for your use case though) and your Databricks regex is `^(id*)` which is basically equivalent to `^id*` which is wrong (ex: `ill` would match)

Answer (score 3):

**tl;dr**

So just a brief explanation over your problem, because I think just because you could solve this specific problem without knowing the reason and the logic behind it, doesn't mean the problem will never happen again. When you use asterisk in regular expressions, it means any number of some pattern (including 0), so in your first case:

```scala
val firstRegex = "^id*".r
// this means the string must start with "i", and can have any consecutive number of "d"s appended to it.
firstRegex.matches("i") // true
firstRegex.matches("idddddddd") // true
firstRegex.matches("iPhone") // false, the expression only accepts sequence of "d"s appended to a single "i"
```

About your second regex, as you can guess, it accepts any number of string "id" appended to each other (including 0):

```scala
val secondRegex = "^(id)*".r

secondRegex.matches("ididididid") // true
secondRegex.matches("idi") // false
secondRegex.matches("") // true, zero "id"s
```

**Wildcard**

So in your case, you want your column name to start with string `id`, no matter the rest. dot (`.`) is that special character in almost all the regular expression engines, that matches everything. Knowing that, you can say

> I want my column to start with "id", and any number(asterisk) of any character(wildcard) after that

So:

```scala
@ val columnNamePattern = "^id.*".r 
columnNamePattern: scala.util.matching.Regex = ^id.*

@ columnNamePattern.matches("identifier") 
res15: Boolean = true

@ columnNamePattern.matches("merchant_name") 
res16: Boolean = false
```

Comment: Well said, great explanation! A general link to a regex cheat sheet is all I would like to add: https://www.rexegg.com/regex-quickstart.html (for reference and better understanding of all the various features and capabilities)

Answer (score 0):

answer was ^(id) without the trailing *

[screenshot of working notebook](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PvEGs.png)

Comment: This answer simply gives the solution that worked for you without addressing the actual problem you encountered with using regex.

Comment: Please accept the other solution, as it provides specificity and clarity as to _why_ your attempts did not work as expected. Additionally, it addresses some potential shortcomings of the solution that *naively* works (but would still match on "idid" for instance, which is likely not intended).

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).